# Prevent Chrome from discovering my Google account

Tags: google-chrome, privacy, google-accounts

I use Chrome and have all the privacy settings to the max.  I never signed in to Chrome or made any type of Chrome account.  For privacy, I avoid being signed in to Google unless I need to; then I sign out when I'm done.  Otherwise, I search Google without being signed in.

To my shock, I signed in to Google, went to print something out from Chrome, pressed "Choose Printers", and saw Chrome display my Google account name and want to associate printers with it.  I was shocked, because I never made a Chrome account.  Somehow, signing in to Google must have told Chrome the details of my account - which I definitely do not want.

How can I tell Chrome: Don't look at, track, or monitor my Google account?

Comment: Google account Is you Chrome account, all Google products (Voice, Maps, Photos, Chrome, etc) use a common Google account. Chrome always remembers accounts, although not credentials unless you allow it to. It will remember every account used in Chrome forever if you don't clear it. If this is a problem you should change browsers.

Comment: @acejavelin I don't think your correct.  If I sign in to Google, that shouldn't sign me in to Chrome.  Chrome is a local application, it's not a website.  If you are correct, how do I clear Chrome's memory of such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome is heavily integrated with Google services, and as such links itself to your account when you first log in.

You can clear this information using the instructions [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2390059?hl=en).

> ### Option 1. Sign out of Chrome
>
> 1. In the top-right corner of the browser window, click the Chrome menu Chrome menu.
> 2. Select Settings.
> 3. Under "Sign in," click Disconnect your Google Account.
> 4. In the confirmation dialog that appears, click Disconnect account.
>
> ### Option 2. Stop and Clear Synced Data
>
> If you want to stop your Google Account from syncing to Chrome
>   altogether, or need to reset sync, you can "stop and clear" your
>   synced data.
>
> To stop and clear your synced data or reset a sync passphrase, follow
>   these steps:
>
> 1. Open your Google Dashboard. Make sure you are signed in to your Google Account.
> 2. Click Reset sync to stop syncing and clear all of your synced data.
> 3. Click OK.
>
> ### Option 3. Remove yourself or another person from Chrome permanently
>
> 1. In the top-right corner of the browser window, click the button for the current user. (It might show a name or email address.)
> 2. Select Switch person.
> 3. Mouse over the person you want to remove.
> 4. In the top-right corner of the person’s card, click the downward arrow.
> 5. Click Remove This Person.
> 6. In the confirmation dialog that appears, click Remove This Person.

Alternatively, if you wish to have a Chrome browser *without* any of the Google experience, consider using the open source software it is based on, [Chromium](http://www.chromium.org/Home).